# Overlapping dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a clickable drop down menu, after putting a `border` on `dropbtn` class, my dropdown `dropdown-content` menu overlaps with the dropdown `button` border `dropbtn`.

I can add `margin-top:15px` to `dropdown-content` class to fix this but is there any way to set this automatically?

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f25pjb14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery to achieve the desired effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content").css("margin-top", $(".dropbtn").css("border-width"));
});
```

which sets the `margin-top` of `.dropdown-content` to the value of `border-width` of `.dropbtn`.
here is a preview: [jsfiddle.net/rrxmw3b3/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/rrxmw3b3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes you want, as it is designed, you need to specify the 15px. Another option is:

```
.dropbtn {
   ...
   position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    ...
    top: 15px;
}
```

Here the preview: http://jsfiddle.net/bvdgw9vc/